# Prove ${\lim_{x\to 0}{\sqrt{x} \cos{(1/\sqrt{x})}}=0}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Re-working homework problems that I missed in preparation for exam.  I originally lost points on this problem because I applied the product of limits which was incorrect because $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}(\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}})}$ does not exist.  Please verify the following proof (I've been struggling with epsilon-delta proofs):

$$
\left| \sqrt{x} \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right|<\epsilon\\
\implies\left|\sqrt{x}\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right|^2<\epsilon^2\\
\implies\left|x\cos^2{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right|<\epsilon^2\\
\implies\left|x\right|<\epsilon^2=\delta~~~~~~\mbox{(because }\cos^2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})\leq 1)\\
\therefore |x|<\delta\implies\left| \sqrt{x} \cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right|<\epsilon\\
AND\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sqrt{x}\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)=0
$$

Comment: It sounds good. Just nitpicking: $\delta = \varepsilon^{2}$. You could also apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @user1337 Thank you for the detail.  I fixed it.  How would I apply the squeeze theorem?

Comment: -sqrt(x)<=sqrt(x)cos(anything)<=sqrt(x) Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: That would have been so much easier.  Thank you.

Comment: The third implication does not hold in general. Take for example some (arbitrarily large)  $x$ such that $\cos(\frac1{\sqrt{x}})=0$. If only works the other way round.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger You gave me a lot to think about here, but choosing arbitrarily large x simply means an arbitrarily large $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.  Since we're taking $\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$, as $x$ increases, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ approaches $0$ and the $\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$ approaches $1$.  Even if $x$ is extremely large, if $|x|$ is less than $\delta=\epsilon^2$ then $|\sqrt{x}\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}|<\epsilon$.  As $x$ approaches $0$, $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ get very small.